# UIPopoverController Not Animating

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have an iPad app that has an `MKMapView` embedded in a `UINavigationController` which is displayed in a `UITabBar`. I am displaying a popover controller over the map with

```
UIPopoverController *myPopoverController =
    [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myContentView]
     autorelease];

[myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:myRect
                                     inView:mapView
                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                   animated:YES];
```

The popover displays fine. However, it does not have the nice animated effect: it just immediately appears onscreen. Similarly, when I dismiss it it just disappears without any animation.

Anybody have any idea how I can get the animation to work? Should I try displaying it from another view? Is there some property on something that I might have neglected to set?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Despite the `animated:(BOOL)` parameter, it appears popovers never animate when presented. I've tried a dozen first and third party apps.

The dismissal *should* animate however, provided you pass `YES` to `dismissPopoverAnimated:(BOOL)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your popover animates outside the map view, I would try placing the map view into a container view whose frame is the same size as the map view's. From there, it's trivial to present the popover in the container view.

According to Apple's documentation, MKMapView isn't supposed to be subclassed, so like UIWebView, it strikes me as one of those views whose guts are better left untouched.